# Restrict users switching from one to other user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, users, linux-kernel

I have 5 users in my linux machine (user1,user2,user3,user4,user5) and my requirement is each user except user5. Remaining 4 users able to switch only user5. But they don't want to switch any other users like user1 don't want to switch to user2,user3 and user4 only that user1 want to shift to user5. Same as like that other users they want to switch only to user5 but not the remaining users.
Please help me out with my requirement

Comment: Take a step back and explain the /End Result/ that you are trying to achieve (not the difficulties with your current attempt to solve it).  
What you want probably /can/ be done (through /very/ careful use of sudo) but it is highly unlikely to the /best/ solution.

Comment: Do you want all users to be able to run commands (which commands?) as `user5` or just have access to `user5`'s files? Why are you doing this? I sense am "XY Problem"

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers (who have better answers). Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our way to help you improve your question. All facts about your system and problem should go in the Question with [edit].  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Help us help you.